# What is the difference between curl and wget?

Tags: downloads, wget, curl

Both of these `curl` and `wget` are use for downloading files, etc. What are the notable differences one might take in account in order chose one over the other?

Comment: Define "proper use"

Comment: Regarding the vote to close as opinion-based: how does asking about the difference between two tools encourage opinion-based answers?

Comment: @MichaelMartin-Smucker "Suppose I need to download a web page lets say www.google.com, should I look for wget or curl ?" what is that if not opinion-based?

Comment: @muru, It depends on what you mean by "download a web page". If you mean send an http request and receive back the results, curl is ideal. If you mean download a page, other pages it links to, and related assets, curl will not work, and wget is the only option. There are factual differences between them which make this not opinion based.

Comment: The fact that the question is unclear does not make it de facto opinion based. There are factual, non-opinion differences between the tools, and a question about which should be used would be reasonably assumed to be a request for information about such differences.

Comment: @barbecue if question is unclear, still vote to close it.

Comment: @barbecue further, the part for defining "proper use" was itself added after someone requested clarification. If the question is in fact about a single web page from an HTTP server, the question is opinion-based.

Comment: @muru "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts" yet all of the answers here seem to provide valuable insight based on verifiable differences between the tools.

Comment: @MichaelMartin-Smucker because only two answers provide recommendations. A.B. says: "After you've defined "proper use", use wget," (because recursive, yet the question talks of *one page*). The second answer says: "Use it according to your requirement and which feature you want to use along with downloading." ... which is common sense.  The rest of these answers and the other answers are just feature comparisons.

Comment: @muru you seem to be focusing on the "download... www.google.com" example, which was added to the question later. Given the title, the true question is "What is the difference...?" so of course the answers focus on feature comparisons.

Comment: @MichaelMartin-Smucker if the title is all there is, why do we have a question body? That part was added later as a *clarification*, which speaks volumes about the question's quality in the first place.

Comment: @muru I guess we just have different interpretations of the sentiment behind the question. In my interpretation, the sentiment is: "I've heard of these two tools which seem to do the same thing. What is the difference between them, and when should I choose one over the other? What about in this specific case?" ...which seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: Over on [unix.se]: [What is the difference between curl and wget?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47434/what-is-the-difference-between-curl-and-wget)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After you've defined "proper use", use `wget`.

Why? That's why:

Recursive! wget's major strong side compared to curl is its ability to download recursively, or even just download everything that is referred to from a remote resource, be it a HTML page or a FTP directory listing.

---

<sub>Shameless copied from [here](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html)</sub>

### `curl`

- *library*. `curl` is powered by `libcurl` – a cross-platform library with a stable API that can be used by each and everyone. This difference is major since it creates a completely different attitude on how to do things internally. It is also slightly harder to make a library than a "mere" command line tool.
- *pipes*. `curl` works more like the traditional Unix `cat` command, it sends more stuff to `stdout`, and reads more from `stdin` in a "everything is a pipe" manner. `wget` is more like `cp`, using the same analogue.
- *Single shot*. `curl` is basically made to do single-shot transfers of data. It transfers just the URLs that the user specifies, and does not contain any recursive downloading logic nor any sort of HTML parser.
- *More protocols*. `curl` supports FTP, FTPS, Gopher, HTTP, HTTPS, SCP, SFTP, TFTP, TELNET, DICT, LDAP, LDAPS, FILE, POP3, IMAP, SMB/CIFS, SMTP, RTMP and RTSP. Wget only supports HTTP, HTTPS and FTP.
- *More portable*. `curl` builds and runs on lots of more platforms than `wget`. For example: OS/400, TPF and other more "exotic" platforms that aren't straight-forward Unix clones.
- *More SSL libraries and SSL support*. `curl` can be built with one out of eleven (11!) different SSL/TLS libraries, and it offers more control and wider support for protocol details. `curl` supports public key pinning.
- *HTTP auth*. `curl` supports more HTTP authentication methods, especially over HTTP proxies: Basic, Digest, NTLM and Negotiate
- *SOCKS*. `curl` supports several SOCKS protocol versions for proxy access
- *Bidirectional*. `curl` offers upload and sending capabilities. `wget` only offers plain HTTP POST support.
- *HTTP multipart/form-data sending*, which allows users to do HTTP "upload" and in general emulate browsers and do HTTP automation to a wider extent
- `curl` supports `gzip` and inflate Content-Encoding and does automatic decompression
- `curl` offers and performs decompression of Transfer-Encoded HTTP, wget doesn't
- `curl` supports HTTP/2 and it does dual-stack connects using Happy Eyeballs
- *Much more developer activity*. While this can be debated, I consider three metrics here: mailing list activity, source code commit frequency and release frequency. Anyone following these two projects can see that the curl project has a lot higher pace in all these areas, and it has been so for 10+ years. Compare on openhub

---

### `wget`

- `wget` is command line only. There's no library.
- *Recursive*! `wget`'s major strong side compared to curl is its ability to download recursively, or even just download everything that is referred to from a remote resource, be it a HTML page or a FTP directory listing.
- *Older*. `wget` has traces back to 1995, while `curl` can be tracked back no earlier than the end of 1996.
- *GPL*. `wget` is 100% GPL v3. curl is MIT licensed.
- *GNU*. `wget` is part of the GNU project and all copyrights are assigned to FSF. The curl project is entirely stand-alone and independent with no organization parenting at all with almost all copyrights owned by Daniel.
- `wget` requires no extra options to simply download a remote URL to a local file, while `curl` requires `-o` or `-O`.
- `wget` supports the Public Suffix List for handling cookie domains, curl does not.
- `wget` supports only GnuTLS or OpenSSL for SSL/TLS support
- `wget` supports only Basic auth as the only auth type over HTTP proxy
- `wget` has no SOCKS support
- Its ability to recover from a prematurely broken transfer and continue downloading has no counterpart in curl.
- `wget` can be typed in using only the left hand on a qwerty keyboard!

Comment: Yes, wget is great for mirroring!

Comment: "The curl project is entirely stand-alone and independent with no organization parenting at all with almost all copyrights owned by Daniel." Not sure that's a bad thing...

Comment: "Its ability to recover from a prematurely broken transfer and continue downloading has no counterpart in curl." Did I understand this sentence wrong? Isn't `curl -C -` continuing broken download?

Comment: Why do you recommend *wget*? Even after looking at the comparisons which you wrote yourself, *curl* sounds to be far superior. *`wget can be typed in using only the left hand on a qwerty keyboard!`*, *`wget requires no extra options to simply download a remote URL to a local file, while curl requires -o or -O.`* **WTF??**

Comment: Size matters too: on a fresh ubuntu image, wget size is 2M vs. curl 5M packed (with deps, x3 total unpacked)

Answer (score 21):

There are many tools that can download like `curl` ,`snarf` , `wget`, `pavuk`, `fget`, `fetch`, `lftp` ,`aria2` , `HTTrack` etc. Use it according to your requirement and which feature you want to use along with downloading.
Check [feature table](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/comparison-table.html)  and use accordingly .

**Curl :**

- Curl support more protocol  FTP, FTPS, HTTP, HTTPS, SCP, SFTP, TFTP,
  TELNET, DICT, LDAP, LDAPS, FILE, POP3, IMAP, SMTP, RTMP and RTSP
- Curl support more SSL libraries
- Curl supports more HTTP authentication methods, especially over HTTP
  proxies: Basic, Digest, NTLM and Negotiate
- Curl is powered by libcurl -a cross-platform library with a stable
  API that can be used by each and everyone

**Wget :**

- While wget supports HTTP, HTTPS and FTP
- Wget supports only GnuTLS or OpenSSL for SSL/TLS support
- Wget supports only Basic auth as the only auth type over HTTP proxy
- Wget is command line tool only, it has no library.

**Important Resources for more info :**

- Here is good explanation [curl vs Wget](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html).
- Table of features : [Compare cURL Features with Other Download
  Tools](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/comparison-table.html)
- Detail of curl supported features : [Features -- what can curl do](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/features.html)
- Detail of wget supported features : [wget features](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Overview)

Answer (score 4):

They have much functionality in common, but `curl` has more options. For `wget` it may occasionally be sufficient to leaf through `man wget`, but for `curl` I need to study [this webpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) in a browser. I believe anything your browser can do, `curl` can do as well.

Answer (score 4):

There's another difference between wget and curl which I think is significant.

Wget is a stand-alone command line utility that's intended primarily for retrieving internet content quickly and simply.

Curl on the other hand is basically a terminal front end for the powerful libcurl library. Libcurl provides a very powerful set of tools for working with URLs in all their forms and flavors, and is available for almost all languages and platforms. Curl basically gives you the ability to use this library in shell scripts.